# В каком предложении есть обращение?

Tags: обращение, просторечия

1. Тюлени — водные млекопитающие отряда ластоногих. Тюлени широко распространены в морях и некоторых озерах. Детенышей рождают на суше.
2. — Ой, глянь-ко, что это?
   — А! То тюлень, тюлень, сынок, подплыл на нас поглядеть.
   — Знаю. А где он живет?
   — В море живет. Днем рыбу промышляет, а ночью к берегу плывет, на камнях спит в местах глухих...

Я думаю, обращение здесь:
— Ой, глянь-ко, что это?
— А! То тюлень, тюлень, сынок, подплыл на нас поглядеть.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы: конечно же, обращение присутствует во втором отрывке — это слово "сынок".

Сынок — одиночное существительное в именительном падеже (лицо, к которому обращена речь); не является членом предложения (можно без потери смысла изъять из предложения: *То тюлень, тюлень подплыл на нас поглядеть*); выделено запятыми.
[**Обращения**](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/728-212_obrascheniya.html)

Меня заинтересовал язык повествования (думаю, это один из говоров).
На самом деле авторский текст выглядит так ([Ю. Казаков. Никишкины тайны](https://books.google.ee/books?id=FZcAAPp4DtcC&pg=PT445&lpg=PT445&dq=%D0%9E%D0%B9,%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE?%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=YFtCc6eXmE&sig=ACfU3U0waPF1IMyvFPMYzLnKnNetGiJFUw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwja2rnwjMvrAhXSvosKHd2BDFoQ6AEwAnoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9E%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%3F%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false)).

> — Ой, глянь-ко, что это?
> — Где?
> — Эвон кажется...
> — А! То тюлень. Тюлень, сынок, подплыл на нас поглядеть.
> — Знаю. А где он живет?
> — В море живет. Днем рыбу промышляет, а ночью к берегу плывет, на камнях спит в местах глухих на съемных коргах.

Глянь-ко = глянь-ка, погляди-ка.
[Эвон](http://slovonline.ru/slovar_efremova/b-28/id-121326/evon.html) — вон, вон там.
То тюлень = это тюлень.
[Корга](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/sea/4053)
В словаре Даля:
Подводный камень, гряда, риф; каменистый, отлогий берег *сиб.* хрящеватое дно озера.

В Морском словаре:
Небольшой каменный островок или подводный камень в море (арх.).
Плотное песчаное или каменистое дно озера или реки (арх.).
Каменистая банка в море; гряда камней, иногда надводная, а иногда покрываемая водою во время прилива (арх.).
Мелкое место в реке или озере (онеж.).